# using csv as a schema format with multiple tables

Tags: sql

I would like to use csv to describe a database schema. I found examples but for a single table, is there a standardized specification (or ideas, tracks etc.) for describing multiple (and linked) tables ?

Comment: Please look here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

CSV file only can have data with delimiter ( one line for one row and field separated with another delimiter)

So if you store data from different table in the same CSV, all data will be added to only one table.

best way is create different csv or choose another format ( why not sql ?)